# How to run OpenWRT as Kubernetes pod on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openwrt, raspberry-pi4

I have searched this question on Google, but didn't find any related answer or solution.

As I knew, OpenWRT could run as Docker container on Raspberry Pi. So how about run OpenWRT as k8s pod on Pi? Thanks.

Comment: Well what about running openwrt on k8s? Are you expecting a tutorial? I'm not sure what the question is.